# How to archive Jira version with REST API

Tags: json, rest, jira

I'm trying to automatically archived versions in Jira.

So far, I've been able to create and update versions in Jira with the REST API, but no luck with archiving a version.

I've try just setting the field archived from false to true using something like this:

{ "update" : { "archived" : [{ "set" : true }] } }

I've also try to set the released field at the same time.
I did also try to send all version's fields with archived updated.
All without success, so I'm guessing there is something else that needs to be done in that case.

So to resume this, I am mainly trying to find the exact json content to archive a version since I already know how to use JIRA REST API.

Thanks.

Comment: There are many questions: Which Jira Version? Which Jira REST API Version? Which Jira REST Resouce (issue, project, ...)?

Comment: @andih: I assume the OP is referring to [version resources](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA/Managing+Versions).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[As described in the API docs](https://docs.atlassian.com/jira/REST/latest/#d2e5124), versions don't use an `"update"` field for updating.  Simply `PUT` the data `{"archived": true}` to `http://JIRA-SERVER/rest/api/2/version/VERSION-ID`.

Comment: Seems like I was doing a mistake somewhere earlier because I did try it without success, but now it works.

Comment: In fact, I think the problem are the dates. Jira seems picky about it. It works if I keep only the field that needs updating.